# Issue with appcompat-v7 and NotificationManagerCompat

Tags: android

I'm trying to use

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

to determine if Push Notifications are allowed for my app or not. However it does not compile with this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
Log.d(TAG, "Allowed PushNotes: " + NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled());
                                                                         ^
symbol:   method areNotificationsEnabled()
location: class NotificationManagerCompat
```

It's imported like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
```

These are the parts of the build.gradle relevant for this I guess:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.9"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true        
    }
```

And this is the dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App Gradle file, `com.android.support:support` should be minimum 24 
`compileSdkVersion` have to be 24

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 24

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0"